# command to Move or Copy 100 Thousands of text files from one folder to another folder based on particular selected date

Tags: command-line

`dir1` is having n(100 thousands) number of `.txt` files with different date of creation so here I want to copy or move those files with one selected date to the other directory

I'm looking for a command line solution not a scripting one.

Comment: What date would that be ?

Comment: "Command line" and "scripting" are the same thing...

Comment: @fkraiem, I think what he means is command run from the _terminal_ not one run from a _script file_.

Comment: @George All commands can be run indifferently from the terminal or from a script.

Comment: @fkraiem, yes I know but he wants one that is _typed_ directly into the terminal, [at least that's my interpretation] and not one that comes from script file.

Comment: Ubuntu [does not keep track of the date/time files were created](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created), only when they were last modified. If they have not been changed in any way since they were created then the existing answer should work for you, though.

Comment: Rsync is a great utility for this! http://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward

Answer (score 1):

This script typed in the terminal should be able to do what you want, although your exact time is still unknown. Run it from the directory with the files inquestion:

```
find -type f -ctime 0 -exec mv -t /new/dir/location/ {} +
```

**Description:**

find files that where created in the `ctime` and `mv` them to `/new/dir/location`

**NOTE:**

for `ctime`:

- `0`  means past 24hrs
- `-1` means less than 24hrs
- `+1` means more than 24hrs
- `1`  means 24hrs

`{} +` append values of `find` command to be acted on by `mv` command

`find` defaults to search in the current directory but you can always add a location like this: `find /dir/to/search`.